# validation standard can't be used

Tags: grails

I am very new to Grails. In Grails when we use `generate-all` rather than `create` then can we use the validation put in the static constraints in the domain class? If not then what is the use if we are using `generate-all` rather than `create`? So I have to do the validation manually rather than using the predefined validation.

Comment: how in any way do you think script will know your validation rules? you have to add the validation rules manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to mention your validation rules to get desired output.